# SwiftUI Make a list that shows only a certain amount of rows

Tags: swiftui, ios13, swiftui-list

I have recently started messing around with SwiftUI and so far it is great. I have however ecnountered a problem that I can't seem to find an answer to.

I am trying to create this design:

[image: What I want to create]

As you can see here is a tableview (a list) which rows have a smaller tableview (a list) inside them. The task was pretty simple while using IB, but with swiftUI I can't seem to find a way to limit the number of rows to only the amount I need or to manually set the lists height based on the number of rows (keep in mind those rows can also be variable in height).

My code so far only consist of creating the List and adding 2 test rows:

```
List {
    OrderItemRow()
    OrderItemRow()
}
```

But as you can see SwiftUI automatically stretches the List to fill all the available space. The effect:
[image]

Comment: For this UI design I'd not select a List, but `ScrollView` of `OrderView`'s

Comment: what did you do to finally resolve it? I have a navigation link out of each row, so wanted to know which one works without much hassle.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the height of your rows, this can be achieved like this:

```swift
List(self.arrayOfAllItemsInOrder(currentOrder)) { item in
    OrderItemRow(currentOrder: order, item:item)
}
.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, rowHeight)
.frame(height: self.arrayOfAllItemsInOrder.reduce(0) { i, _ in i + rowHeight })
```

This will calculate the full size of the list based on `rowHeight` and limit the frame's height.

Note that if the size of your row goes beyond `rowHeight`, the entire calculation will be messed up and you will probably be seeing half (or missing entire) cells.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a List using a ForEach to show your orders and a nested ForEach to show items in an order. The key is to manage the Data being supplied to each ForEach to the number of items desired and also to construct appropriate Row Views for OrderHeaderRow, OrderItemRow, etc.

```
struct OrdersView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(header: Text("Current Order")) {
                OrderHeaderRow(order: currentOrder)
                ForEach(self.arrayOfAllItemsInOrder(currentOrder)) { item in
                    OrderItemRow(currentOrder: order, item:item)
                }
                OrderTotalRow(order: order)
                ActionButtonsRow(order:order)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Previous Orders")) {
                ForEach(self.arrayOfAllPreviousOrders) { order in
                    OrderHeaderRow(order: order)
                    ForEach(self.arrayOfAllItemsInOrder(order)) { item in
                        OrderItemRow(order: order, item:item)
                    }
                    OrderTotalRow(order: order)
                    ActionButtonsRow(order:order)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that without a mechanism for setting the height for that list it automaticaly fills the whole screen, messing up with the design. As you can see in my code snipped I am only populating this list with 2 rows. Is there a way to limit rows? Or to set the height manually?

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to force the SwiftUI List to do something that it's not intended to do. Instead of placing your Order Header and Order Footer views outside of the List, just make them Rows inside your List.  FYI, Rows in a List do not have to be all the same type of View. I will edit my answer to show some pseudocode that demonstrates what I'm talking about.